# add new row to end of uitableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

Im trying to add news row after user scrolls to ends of view.

the first 10 row comes from first page fetch and then i reload my table.

this is frist page code :

```
SubViewController *svc =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Subview"];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0),
                   ^{
                       ParseOperation *p = [[ParseOperation alloc]init];

                       p.code = selection_code.text;
                       [p main];
                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
                                       {


                                          svc.entries = p.appRecordList;
                                          [svc.tableView reloadData];

                                      });
                   });

    [svc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];
```

and for second page i find the end of scrolls item with this:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
......

   if ((unsigned long)indexPath.row == [self.entries count] - 1){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0),
                       ^{
                           ParseOperation *p = [[ParseOperation alloc]init];
                           AppRecord *appRecord = [self.entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


                           p.lastid = appRecord.ids;
                           [p main];
                           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
                                          {

                                              SubCategoryViewController *svc =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SubView"];

                                               svc.entries = p.appRecordList;
                                              [svc.tableView reloadData];

                                          });
                       });

    }
    return cell;
```

the parsoperation words well and new rss items fetched. but the table not refreshing.

edit (adding numberOfRowInSection code)

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSUInteger count = [self.entries count];

    // if there's no data yet, return enough rows to fill the screen
    if (count == 0)
    {
        return kCustomRowCount;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your numberOfRowsInSection code?

Comment: sure iv added to end of my question.

Comment: Answer a few question 1. You want to insert a row when you come to end of the tableView? Is there any problem if you load the data before scrolling down to the end of tableview?

Comment: @Rashad yes that what i exactly want to do. i want to implement the method that when user comes to end of list , it gets the last row index and send it to url and when new rows fetched, adds it to ends of list.
i can fetch data with no problem when it comes to ends of list , but dont know how to adds it in ends of uitableview

Comment: @AndreyMarkov is there something like you will show news cell after 10 rows and another after another 10 rows or you need to show only at the last cell of tableview

Comment: @CharanGiri yes this method will goes for next 10 row too. like if u go down to row 20, it will load next 10 row and added to tableview.

Comment: @AndreyMarkov will you call service for 10 rows individually(once user scrolls to 10th row then call service again) or at once you will get information from server

Comment: @CharanGiri yes the service will gets called if i hit the end of 10 row, and then new unique 10 will get fetched from service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code doesn't make complete sense to me, it looks like you have two different classes, `SubViewController` and `SubCategoryViewController`, which one contains the tableView? You are instantiating both with the identifier "SubView". It looks to me like you can delete the entire SubCategoryViewController-class, and only use SubViewController. I might misunderstand their purpose though.

Either way, in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`-method, you are instantiating a new, empty View Controller. 
Look at your own code from inside `cellForRow..` here:

```
SubCategoryViewController *svc =[self.storyboard 
                         instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SubView"];
svc.entries = p.appRecordList;                
[svc.tableView reloadData];
```

What this code does, is to instantiate a new `SubCategoryViewController`, also called 'svc'. It has nothing to do with your current view controller. It is another one, with its own table view. You are pushing your new data to a new, invisible view controller, and you are never using it. After `[.. reloadData]`, your new view controller is deleted.

It looks to me like you should be using `[self ..]` rather than the new, useless `svc`.

Instead of the code above, try this(and remove the subCategory-instantiation):

```
self.entries = p.appRecordList;                
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Keep in mind, this code will replace the data currently inside `self.entries` with the new data. If your new data is another page, then you should append the data first, or else it will always be 10 rows in your table.
I don't know what type of object `entries` (your data source) is, so I can't tell you how to append the data. If it's an `NSArray`, you can do something like this:

```
NSArray *temp = [self.entries arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:p.appRecordList];
self.entries = temp;
```

If it's an `NSMutableArray` you can simply go `[self.entries addObjectsFromArray:p.appRecordList];`. If you're using something else, I'm sure there are appending methods for them as well.

Note: If I'm wrong about `SubView..` and `SubCategoryView..`, please comment the difference between the two, and I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: that was the problem (using double instantiation) . after using self and arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray it fixed out.Thanks for nice answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use insertAtIndexPath method for UITableView inserting new row below the last object of tableView.

```
  -(void)insertRowInTable:(NSArray*)DictOfWebData{
    NSMutableArray *mutArrOfIndexPath=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        int count=arrOfTbleView.count;
        for (NSDictionary *dict in [DictOfWebData objectForKey:@"link"]) {
            [arrOfTbleView addObject:dict];
            [mutArrOfIndexPath addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:count inSection:0]];
            count++;

        }
        [_tblVwOFWebData beginUpdates];
        [_tblVwOFWebData insertRowsAtIndexPaths:mutArrOfIndexPath withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [_tblVwOFWebData endUpdates];
       }
```

And call this method from scrollViewDidEndDragging method and before calling this method ,you have to get data from webservice ..

I think this will help you..

Comment: thanks for answer iv tied this but there is a few error :
in "[arrOfTbleView addObject:dict];"    im passing value to class like this :SubCategoryViewController *svc =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SubView"];
svc.entries = p.appRecordList; and there is no datasource in my class

Answer (score 1):

Try this hope this will help your requirement. When you call service for the first time you will get a list of 10 elements in an array format. So when you add this elements to your array take an extra variable as "isAdv" and set "0" to it once loop is completed(where you will add elements to your array) then add your advertisement along with this add variable as "isAdv" and set "1" . so now your array will contain 11 objects. in cell configure check

```
if(isAdv==1)
{
// this is your news cell
}
else
{
// this your normal cell to display your info which comes from server
}
```

In Detail example

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
menuTableView=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 404) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
menuTableView.delegate=self;
menuTableView.dataSource=self;
menuTableView.separatorColor=[UIColor grayColor];
[self.view addSubview:menuTableView];
NSArray *serverResponseArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10", nil];
finalArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i=0; i<serverResponseArray.count; i++) {

    NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dict setObject:serverResponseArray[i] forKey:@"cellinfo"];
    [dict setObject:@"false"  forKey:@"isAdv"];
    [finalArray addObject:dict];
}
NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dict setObject:@"adv url " forKey:@"cellinfo"];
[dict setObject:@"true"  forKey:@"isAdv"];
[finalArray addObject:dict];
NSLog(@"%d",finalArray.count);
NSLog(@"%@",finalArray);

}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return finalArray.count;
}
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 40;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
    if ([[finalArray[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"isAdv"] isEqualToString:@"false"]) {

        cell.textLabel.text =[finalArray[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"cellinfo"];

    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.text =[finalArray[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"cellinfo"]; // you can place imageview or something to show news here

    }
    NSLog(@"%f",tableView.contentOffset.y);
    NSLog(@"%d",[finalArray count]*40);



    return cell;
}

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
CGFloat height = scrollView.frame.size.height;

CGFloat contentYoffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

CGFloat distanceFromBottom = scrollView.contentSize.height - contentYoffset;

if(distanceFromBottom < height)
{
    NSLog(@"end of the table");
    [self callserviceagain];
    return;
}
}


-(void)callserviceagain
{
NSArray *serverResponseArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"11",@"12",@"13",@"14",@"15",@"16",@"17",@"18",@"19",@"20", nil];

for (int i=0; i<serverResponseArray.count; i++) {

    NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dict setObject:serverResponseArray[i] forKey:@"cellinfo"];
    [dict setObject:@"false"  forKey:@"isAdv"];
    [finalArray addObject:dict];
}
NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dict setObject:@"adv url " forKey:@"cellinfo"];
[dict setObject:@"true"  forKey:@"isAdv"];
[finalArray addObject:dict];
NSLog(@"%d",finalArray.count);
NSLog(@"%@",finalArray);
[menuTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: thanks man for answer ,  this method will definitely help me after i fetch the record for second time. problem was how to insert and added to perior list but Sti answer fixed that.